# Why does Apache serve different directories when accessed from different machines?

Tags: apache, osx-mountain-lion, httpd.conf

I'm trying to configure Apache on OS X 10.8.2 so that the default "system" site is accessible from other machines, while the "user" site is not. In `httpd.conf`I have

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"

<Directory />
    Options -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

and in `ME.conf` I have

```
<Directory "/Users/ME/Sites">
    Options Indexes -FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

This behaves as intended when accessed from the hosting machine: `http://localhost/~ME/` maps to `/Users/ME/Sites` and `http://localhost` maps to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. But when I acces the hostng machine from a different machine, `http://hostingmachine` doesn't work, and `http://hostingmachine/~ME/` maps to `/Library/WebServer/Documents`. What have I done to deserve that? Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do, or at least something close?

Comment: I am not sure if I am following your question.  Are you expecting to be able to to access this server from another machine using localhost?

Comment: @MikeBrant: Sorry, typo. Fixed.